# Delete unimportant text from file in dash

Tags: shell, dash-shell

I have a file with too many lines.

Its constructed like:

```
Text
Text
Text

<--!Important Text begins here-->
important Text
Important Text
Important Text

<--!Important Text ends here -->

Unimportant Text
....

<--!Important Text begins here-->
important Text
Important Text
Important Text

<--!Important Text ends here -->

Unimportant Text
....<--!Important Text begins here-->
important Text
Important Text
Important Text

<--!Important Text ends here -->

Unimportant Text
....
```

and so on.

How can i take the important part and save it in a new file?
I am using the dash terminal from Macintosh

Comment: Is this an HTML or XML file?

Comment: its a txt file, it contains html code

Comment: @user3352472 Does these `<--!Important Text ends here -->` markers exists?

Comment: yes, < --!Important Text starts here--> and <--!Important Text ends here --> exist and are equal in the file. They exist about 800 times in the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to include the markers then you can do something like:

```
awk '/<--!Important Text begins here-->/,/<--!Important Text ends here -->/' file
```

If you wish to ignore the markers and just print the content between them, you can do:

```
awk '
/<--!Important Text begins here-->/{p=1; next}
/<--!Important Text ends here -->/{p=0}
p' file
```

The first solution is a `regex` range. It tells `awk` to print everything between the range (inclusive). To ignore the markers, you just need to set and unset the flag.

Comment: i tried both and directed the output into a file but the file is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
sed -n '/<--!Important Text begins here-->/,/<--!Important Text ends here -->/ p' \
  infile | 
  fgrep -v -e '<--!Important Text begins here-->' \
           -e '<--!Important Text ends here -->' \
   > outfile
```

Note: Assumes that all `<--!Important Text ...` markers are on a separate line each.

Comment: fgrep:  -e: No such file or directory
fgrep: <!--END OF Rich Snippets: Markup für URL -->: No such file or directory
fgrep:  : No such file or directory
sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence

Comment: @user3352472: Tell me what you get when you run `fgrep --version` - while you're at it, als run `sed --version` and `awk --version`; I'm  unclear what you mean by "dash terminal" - if by "dash" you mean the [dash shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_Almquist_shell), that would be surprising; that said, it's not the _shell_ that matters here, but what versions of the _command-line tools_ you're running.